# Is there a command to show the boot messages?

Tags: server, syslog, dmesg

Is there a command to show the boot messages, which are normally shown on system startup on the console? `dmesg` gives only the kernel messages and `less /var/log/syslog` shows too much information.

Comment: you can see just errors or warnings: `systemctl list-units --failed`
Errors/Warnings:
`sudo journalctl -b -p err` & 
`sudo grep -Ei 'warn|error' /var/log/*g`

Comment: It is helpful and almost always necessary to give full version info in the question. I should not have to read down through comments till you finally give that info. Please update the question with EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```bash
less -r /var/log/boot.log*
```

If it gives a permission denied error:

```bash
sudo less -r /var/log/boot.log*
```

Comment: Note you’ll need to use sudo to access those files; also worth mentioning that you use :n to move to the next file in less (as this command accesses several files).

Comment: My Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 has no /var/log/boot.log, only bootstrap.log but to that file is not written anymore. The file is from August 9th, before my installation. Is there a way to enable logging of the boot process to /var/log/boot.log? On my kubuntu 22.04 boot.log exists and gives the information I want.

Comment: Please add the OS version of your system to the question.